# Similarity of a nested json object

Tags: python

I have some 1000s of nested json object (See sample).

Differences can occur on every level. I want to calculate the similarity of two objects. The higher the level, on which the difference occur the higher the difference of the data-set is. Some fields are related, like name and id.

Any idea? Any module that can take over the job? Thanks a lot, for any help.

json sample:

```
{ "items";[
    {
    "id":"abcd",
    "Name":"Name",
    "Infos": {
        "info1":"info1",
        "info2":"info2"
    },
    "data":{
        "data1":"info1",
        "data2":"info2"
    },
    "packs": [
    {
    "Name":"Name",
    "description":"description"
    },
    {
    "Name1":"Name1",
    "description1":"description1"
    } } {
    "id":"abcd",
    "Name":"Name",
    "Infos": {
        "info1":"info1",
        "info4":"info4"
    },
    "data":{
        "data1":"info1",
        "data2":"info2"
    },
    "packs": [
    {
    "Name3":"Name3",
    "description":"description"
    },
    {
    "Name3":"Name3",
    "description1":"description1"
    } }
```

Comment: What do you mean by similarity? Do you have any metric in mind (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks mrzo. So far, I compared the two objects with the module deepdiff. That module shows the differences between those 2 objects. I just have no idea how to calculate a similarity. At the end, I just want to have a score of object relations. The higher the score, the more similar the those objects. I assume, it is more a binary difference of key/value combinations on different levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
def difference(x,y):
  if isinstance(x, list) and isinstance(y, list):
    return 1+min( difference(a, b) for a, b in zip(x,y) )
  elif isinstance(x, dict) and isinstance(y, dict): 
    return 1+min( difference(a, b) for a, b in zip(x.values(), y.values() )
  else:
    return 1 if x!=y else 0
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Hi Blotosmetek. Thanks a lot! Kind of. Your function shows me that there is a difference between 2 objects, but I also want to see how big the difference is.

Comment: Well, it should return the level on which the difference is found (for example, 2). If it's not what you had in mind, please edit your question…

Comment: Ah, I see. Actually, I need all differences and the level just gives an indication of the the weight of the difference. Have I mentioned that the order is more or less random? Thanks, again. I really appreciate.